# terminal - New User Mac platform

Tags: macos

I am new user to mac, whenever I try to use terminal it displays below error:

```
-bash: export: `:/Users/daautomation1/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/sdk/platform-tools/': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `:/Users/daautomation1/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/sdk/platform-tools/:/Users/daautomation1/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/platform-tools': not a valid identifier
```

Comment: do you have a .bash_profile file in your home directory ?

Answer (score 0):

Try running these commands in Terminal:

```
export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
```